# How to use Rails helpers in coffee script?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, jquery-file-upload

Inside my view I would open a new user page simple like this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

How can I do something similar in coffee script? I have the following situation. User uploads a couple of files and after all files are uploaded he should be redirected to his personal repository of files. This is the coffee script:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#new_update').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
    add: (e, data) ->
      types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
      file = data.files[0]
      if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
        $('#new_update').append(data.context)
      else
        alert("#{file.name} is not a gif, jpeg, or png image file")

      $("#submit_button").on 'click', ->
        data.submit()

    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')

    stop: (e, data) ->
      /* I need to redirect him here */
```

After all files are uploaded `stop` gets triggered and there I need to redirect user to his personal page. How can I do that? I know I can redirect him to home page like this:

```
window.location "/"
```

The problem is how to get `@user` from view to coffeescript. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add a data attribute

```
    #new_update{:"date-target" => @user.id}
```

Then do

```
    window.location.href= "/users/" + $("#new_update").attr("data-target")
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks good but for some reason I am receiving an error on window.location that it is not a function. What can be wrong?

Comment: window.location.href  = "/users/" + $("#new_update").attr("data-target")